# "multihash must be a buffer" error while trying to upload files to ipfs using ipfs.add()

Tags: javascript, node.js, ipfs, js-ipfs

I'm trying to spawn a ipfs node and upload a file to ipfs. But the ipfs.add() method always throws the error "multihash must be a buffer".
Googling suggests that the isBuffer check in node's multihash package is the problem but doesn't provide a solution.

But the same method works when I connect to ipfs node that is running locally using ipfs-http-client. This error occurs only when I try to spawn a node.

This is the code to upload the file

```js
async uploadFile() {
  const IPFS = require('ipfs')
  const ipfs = await IPFS.create()
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      const buffer = Buffer.from(reader.result)
      ipfs.add({content: buffer})
      .then(files => {
        resolve(files)
      })
      .catch(error => reject(error))
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.state.selectedFile)
  })
}
```

This is the error thrown in the console

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: multihash must be a Buffer
at Function.validateCID (0.chunk.js:58311)
at new CID (0.chunk.js:58143)
at new CID (0.chunk.js:58476)
at persist (0.chunk.js:157864)
at :3000/async http:/localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:156829
at async parallelBatch (0.chunk.js:183162)
at async buildFileBatch (0.chunk.js:156903)
at async batch (0.chunk.js:182292)
at async reduceToParents (0.chunk.js:156774)
at async balanced (0.chunk.js:156768)
at async all (0.chunk.js:182254)
at async fileBuilder (0.chunk.js:157010)
at async parallelBatch (0.chunk.js:183162)
at async treeBuilder (0.chunk.js:157803)
at async push../node_modules/ipfs-unixfs-importer/src/index.js.module.exports (0.chunk.js:157711)
at :3000/async http:/localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:119802
at :3000/async http:/localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:119828
at :3000/async http:/localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:119843
at async addAll (0.chunk.js:119787)
at async last (0.chunk.js:182560)
at async IPFS.add (0.chunk.js:120025)
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error today on a project that had a dependency on an old version of the `cids` package.

Try running `npm ls cids` to see if you have a dependency on `cids`. If so, run `npm install cids@latest` to update and see if that fixes things.

Edit to add: I think it was the fact that `cids` depended on an old version of the `multihashes` package that was causing the issue. So if you don't have a dependency on `cids`, run `npm ls` and look for anything that's pulling in an old version of `multihashes`.

Comment: Upgrading direct deps of your project in general will not help here as IPFS will get it's own copy of `cids`.

IPFS exports the `cids` dep it uses so you can use that instead of adding another dep to your project - see https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/docs/MODULE.md#static-types-and-utils

Answer (score 0):

What version of js-ipfs are you using?  That error message was changed to `multihash must be a Uint8Array` about seven months ago so there may be a more recent version available.

Comment: I'm using version 0.5.2. In which version was it changed and is there any way to get rid of this error @achingbrain

Comment: It went out in `cids@1.0.0` which shipped with `ipfs@0.50.0` and `ipfs-core@0.1.0`

Can you share a link to your project? I think some of your dependencies may be out of alignment.